# Cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, polynomials

### Background (skip to definitions)

Euler proved a beautiful theorem about the complex numbers: \$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)\$.

This makes de Moivre's theorem easy to prove:

$$
(e^{ix})^n = e^{i(nx)} \\
(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^n = \cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)
$$

We can plot complex numbers using the two-dimensional Euclidean plane, with the horizontal axis representing the real part and the vertical axis representing the imaginary part. This way, \$(3,4)\$ would correspond to the complex number \$3+4i\$.

If you are familiar with polar coordinates, \$(3,4)\$ would be \$(5,\arctan(\frac 4 3))\$ in polar coordinates. The first number, \$r\$, is the distance of the point from the origin; the second number, \$\theta\$, is the angle measured from the positive \$x\$-axis to the point, counter-clockwise. As a result, \$3 = r \cos \theta\$ and \$4 = r \sin \theta\$. Therefore, we can write \$3+4i\$ as \$r \cos \theta + r i \sin \theta = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = re^{i\theta}\$.

Let us solve the complex equation \$z^n = 1\$, where \$n\$ is a positive integer.

We let \$z = re^{i\theta}\$. Then, \$z^n = r^ne^{in\theta}\$. The distance of \$z^n\$ from the origin is \$r^n\$, and the angle is \$n\theta\$. However, we know that the distance of 1 from the origin is 1, and the angle is \$\theta\$. Therefore, \$r^n=1\$ and \$n\theta=\theta\$. However, if you rotate by \$2π\$ more, you still end up at the same point, because \$2π\$ is just a full circle. Therefore, \$r=1\$ and \$n\theta = 2kπ\$, giving us \$z=e^{2ikπ / n}\$.

We restate our discovery: **the solutions to \$z^n=1\$ are \$z=e^{2ikπ / n}\$**.

A polynomial can be expressed in terms of its roots. For example, the roots of \$x^2-3x+2\$ are 1 and 2, so \$x^{2}-3x+2 = (x-1)(x-2)\$. Similarly, from our discovery above:

$$z^n-1 = \prod^{n-1}_{k=0} (z-e^{2ik\pi / n})$$

However, that product certainly contained roots of other n. For example, take \$n=8\$. The roots of \$z^{4}=1\$ would also be included inside the roots of \$z^{8}=1\$, since \$z^{4}=1\$ implies \$z^{8} = (z^{4})^{2} = 1^{2} = 1\$. Take \$n=6\$ as an example. If \$z^{2}=1\$, then we would also have \$z^{6}=1\$. Likewise, if \$z^{3}=1\$, then \$z^{6}=1\$.

If we want to extract the roots unique to \$z^{n}=1\$, we would need \$k\$ and \$n\$ to share no common divisor except \$1\$. Or else, if they share a common divisor \$d\$ where \$d>1\$, then \$z\$ would be the \$\frac k d\$-th root of \$z^{n / d}=1\$. Using the technique above to write the polynomial in terms of its roots, we obtain the polynomial:

$$\prod_{\substack{0 \le k < n \\ \gcd(k,n) = 1}} (z - e^{2ik\pi / n})$$

Note that this polynomial is done by removing the roots of \$z^{n / d}=1\$ with d being a divisor of \$n\$. We claim that the polynomial above has integer coefficients. Consider the LCM of the polynomials in the form of \$z^{n / d}-1\$ where \$d>1\$ and \$d\$ divides \$n\$. The roots of the LCM are exactly the roots we wish to remove. Since each component has integer coefficients, the LCM also has integer coefficients. Since the LCM divides \$z^{n}-1\$, the quotient must be a polynomial with integer coefficient, and the quotient is the polynomial above.

The roots of \$z^{n}=1\$ all have radius 1, so they form a circle. The polynomial represents the points of the circle unique to n, so in a sense the polynomials form a partition of the circle. Therefore, the polynomial above is the n-th cyclotomic polynomial. (cyclo- = circle; tom- = to cut)

### Definition 1

The n-th cyclotomic polynomial, denoted \$\Phi_n(x)\$, is the unique polynomial with integer coefficients that divide \$x^{n}-1\$ but not \$x^{k}-1\$ for \$k < n\$.

### Definition 2

The cyclotomic polynomials are a set of polynomials, one for each positive integer, such that:

$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{k \mid n} \Phi_k(x)$$

where \$k \mid n\$ means \$k\$ divides \$n\$.

### Definition 3

The \$n\$-th cyclotomic polynomial is the polynomial \$x^{n}-1\$ divided by the LCM of the polynomials in the form \$x^{k}-1\$ where \$k\$ divides \$n\$ and \$k < n\$.

### Examples

1. \$Φ_{1}(x) = x - 1\$
2. \$Φ_{2}(x) = x + 1\$
3. \$Φ_{3}(x) = x^{2} + x + 1\$
4. \$Φ_{30}(x) = x^{8} + x^{7} - x^{5} - x^{4} - x^{3} + x + 1\$
5. \$Φ_{105}(x) = x^{48} + x^{47} + x^{46} - x^{43} - x^{42} - 2x^{41} - x^{40} - x^{39} + x^{36} + x^{35} + x^{34} + x^{33} + x^{32} + x^{31} - x^{28} - x^{26} - x^{24} - x^{22} - x^{20} + x^{17} + x^{16} + x^{15} + x^{14} + x^{13} + x^{12} - x^{9} - x^{8} - 2x^{7} - x^{6} - x^{5} + x^{2} + x + 1\$

### Task

Given a positive integer \$n\$, return the \$n\$-th cyclotomic polynomial as defined above, in a reasonable format (i.e. e.g. list of coefficients is allowed).

### Rules

You may return floating point/complex numbers as long as they round to the correct value.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

### References

- [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

Comment: Maybe add 105 as a test?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't want to type 48 terms

Comment: In definition 2, is the "positive integer" `x`, `n` or `k`?

Comment: @H.PWiz The notation is same as definition 1

Comment: @LeakyNun, Thanks. Just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/29901/194)

Comment: Could someone double check the coefficients of the 105 test case? (not using Wikipedia that is...)

Comment: @JonathanAllan The Haskell solution gives the same result.

Comment: Are floating-point inaccuracies allowed?

Comment: @miles I hate floats with a passion >.< but I'll defend to the death your right to use floats.

Comment: @LeakyNun Is it OK if the floats are complex numbers, in addition to having inaccuracies?

Comment: @xnor I hate complex numbers with a passion >.< but I'll defend to the death your right to use complex numbers.

Comment: May our polynomial have extra leading zeroes?

Comment: May we output complex floating point numbers as long as they yield the correct answer when rounded to the nearest integer/gaussian integer?

Comment: @fireflame241 yes

Answer (score 12):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 120 bytes

```hs
import Data.Complex
p%a=zipWith(\x y->x-a*y)(p++[0])$0:p
f n=foldl(%)[1][cis(2*pi/fromInteger n)^^k|k<-[1..n],gcd n k<2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYs9C4JQFEDn/BV3MFBLU6EltKWWlmhrMIOLPu3xvi6vF5j0382ltsM5nAc@BZNymrgiYx0c0WFyMIokGzxaYjlyunL3CG4DvOP9EGP0DgNaraq0Dv10R14HuuyMbGWwDKusrhr@DPKI@KazRp20Yz2zoMP7XXxEEVdZkuh63TctaBBFXk8jlNBBlm49hYKdecNmYc1Lt5CAZSgvaN3cuJ59a7wFWa4djD/wQSHB/x2nLw)

Gives a list of complex floats that has entries like `1.0000000000000078 :+ 3.314015728506092e-14` due to float inacurracy. A direct method of multiplying out to recover the polynomial from its roots.

[image]

The `fromInteger` is a big concession to Haskell's type system. There's got to be a better way. Suggestions are welcome. Dealing with roots of unity symbolically might also work.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 127 bytes

```hs
(h:t)%q|all(==0)t=[]|1>0=h:zipWith(\x y->x-h*y)t q%q
f n=foldl(%)(1:(0<$[2..n])++[-1])[tail$f k++[0,0..]|k<-[1..n-1],mod n k<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU67DoMwDNz5Cg8gJW2C4kpdEOE3OqQZkChKRAiFZmgR/05DxdABnXXy2eeHqV/dw7l1JaYINBuX2jkipaBBKr1gJaQpZvu82WDI/Q0fXr25OX1ogDEbkxa8bAfXOJJRggURZaouee41PZ8VR01VqK1LW@iiFkzkuV66kiuMnthm/dCAh65Evc4goQUU12SKFIVCtiFOMY6/uOzJVsI/7JZjOrQebtNJX1sfLz8n6wOkQOJPErZ3GMx0/QI)

No imports.

Uses the formula

[image]

Computes Φ_n(x) by dividing the LHS by each of the other terms in the RHS.

The operator `%` does division on polynomials, relying on the remainder being zero. The divisor is assumed to be monic, and is given without the leading 1, and also with infinite trailing zeroes to avoid truncating when doing `zipWith`.

Comment: `[0,0..]` is a byte shorter than `repeat 0`.

Comment: @flawr Divides polynomials. I think it's the same method as your solution.

Comment: It looks damn elegant, I'm gonna have to get a closer look tomorrow:)

Comment: this answer makes me want to learn Haskell.

Comment: @xnor [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##PYs9D4IwFABn@RVvwIQPi0DiYsBFZ@PmgJi8QJGmpX2pNUHif0cW3S53uR6fkis1z2IgYx2c0GFyNAMpPnq0xnISdBWuD24jvNlhZBi9w4DiuErr0E/35HWgP1iwThljQZedUa0K1mGV1VUjnkEekdjq8H6XH1mwKksSrDePpgUEWeT1PEEJHWTpzhtQ8rNo@CKseekWErAc1QWtW5rQi2@NtyIrtIPpBz4MSPB/p/kL)

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
Factor[x^#-1]/Times@@#0/@Most@Divisors@#&
```

Of course, we can always use the built-in, but if we don't, this divides *x*<sup>*n*</sup>-1 by Φ<sub>*k*</sub>(*x*) (computed recursively) for every proper divisor *k* of *n*.

We use `Factor` to get a polynomial at the end. I think the reason this works is that `x^#-1` factors into all the cyclotomic polynomials of divisors of *n*, and then we divide out the ones we don't want.

*-2 bytes thanks to Jenny_mathy, rewriting the `Factor` to only apply to the numerator.*

Comment: This is great! you can save a byte by using `Factor@`

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Doing that seems to parse as `Factor[x^#-1]/Times@@...` instead; if we didn't have brackets there, we'd want parentheses.

Comment: ok... but I have to say that when I tested it, it was giving the right results...

Comment: That's interesting. It means we can save another byte by writing it `Factor[x^#-1]/Times@@...`, and it also means I have no clue how it works.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
Z\"@:@/]XHxvHX~18L*Ze1$Yn
```

Output may be non-integer due to floating-point inaccuracies (which is allowed). The footer does rounding for clarity.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PypGycHKQT82wqOizCOiztDCRysq1VAlMu9/ZL4CCKgqFOWX5qUolOQr5KUmFqUWlyhk5pWkpqcW/Tc0MAUA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>250 236 233 218</s> 216 bytes

This is a verbose version, (@xnor can do it in almost [half the score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143916/24877)) but it is guaranteed to work for any `n` as long as you have enough memory, but it does not use a builtin for generating the n-th cyclotomic polynomial. The input is an arbitrary size integer and the output is a polynomial type with (exact) rational coefficients.

The rough idea here is calculatin the polynomials recursively. For `n=1` or `n` prime it is trivial. For all other numbers this approach basically uses the formula from definition 2

[image]

solved for [image]. Thanks @H.PWiz for quite a bunch of bytes!

```hs
import Math.Polynomial
import Data.Ratio
import NumberTheory
p=powPoly x
q=poly LE
c n|n<2=q[-1,1%1]|isPrime n=sumPolys$p<$>[0..n-1]|1>0=fst$quotRemPoly(addPoly(p n)$q[-1])$foldl1 multPoly[c d|d<-[1..n-1],n`mod`d<1]
```

For `n=105` this yields following polynomial (I tidied up all the `%1` denominators):

```hs
[1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1]
```

The polynomial for `n=15015` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/D7JpKu4M) (the largest coefficient is 23).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxb8IwFIT3/Io3uFKRSISZY6Z2aytE2aJIuLFRrNp@jv0sipT/HhKg053uu7tepl9t7TQZFzASfErqqz3aq0dnpC2e8ZskWR0kGfxPvrL70fHYa4zXIoiAl2UFf8Uw@9l8vBcd@NHXWzE0JV/zF96OJu2jcRq8SNkt/cRCzXbNpqp8OXO@24hzIjZkpIO@N16lUncN4FdsuWpX7IxWWQ4uW1pY04EaVV02/PGz9ieH6qRq3k5OGg8CQqZvisAg9XiZpQO@nW4)

Comment: `+1` for not being a builtin.

Comment: @flawr Why are you using `Rationals`? It seems to work fine without them

Comment: Does it? I had problems with `quotRemPoly`, let me try again then!

Comment: Ah the "problem" was that it yields `Double` coefficients if you don't use `Ratio Integer` instead, which might cause problems for very (very) large `n`.

Comment: Eh... I don't think that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
R÷
ÆḌÇ€FQœ-@Ç×ı2×ØPÆeÆṛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8Hauw20Pd/Qcbn/UtMYt8OhkXYfD7YenH9lodHj64RkBh9tSgdI7Z/8/3P5wx7zDy4qMgNT//4YGpgA)

Outputs as a list of coefficients.

Has floating point AND complex inaccuracies. Footer does rounding to make output prettier.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 36 bytes

```
1+//.@(*/)/@(,.~-)_1^2*%*i.#~1=i.+.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/w219fX1HDS09DX1HTR09Op0NeMN44y0VLUy9ZTrDG0z9bT1Yv9rcinpKain2VqpK@go1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrpCkYG/wHAA)

Uses the formula

[image: formula]

There are some floating-point inaccuracies, but it is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 8 bytes

A built-in.

```
polcyclo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8L8gPye5Mjkn/39afpFGHlDEUEfB0MBAR6GgKDOvBCiipKBrByTSNPI0NTX/AwA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 39 bytes, without built-in

```
f(n)=p=x^n-1;fordiv(n,d,d<n&&p/=f(d));p
```

Using the formula:

\$ \Phi_n(x)=\dfrac{x^{n}-1}{\prod\limits_{\stackrel{d|n}{{}_{d<n}}}\Phi_{d}(x)} \$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCoAwDAC/EhwkgRTbucanCEKodImhiPj7Wpcb7uD8aDWc3ntBI3F5dwspl6tpfdBYWVebZ1@koBJl7yOhgUBiSDEyeKt2DzNB2Ab@DVH/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 32 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{(0,⍵)-⍺×⍵,0}/⍤⌽1,¯1*2×÷×1⍸⍤=⊢∨⍳
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q31dP/UdsEAwA&c=q9Yw0HnUu1VT91HvrsPTgSwdg1r9R71LHvXsNdQ5tN5Qy@jw9MPbD083fNS7Ayhs@6hr0aOOFY96NwMA&f=e9S1qOJR24Q0BWMDLo1HXYu1D603NHw0vftR1yLNRz37H/VNdQ7ReNS55FHHjJrD00GilgpABR0z9MCKmisA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Almost direct port of [miles' J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143927/78410). Returns a polynomial as a vector of coefficients wrapped once, with higher-order terms on the right side.

```
{(0,⍵)-⍺×⍵,0}/⍤⌽1,¯1*2×÷×1⍸⍤=⊢∨⍳    ⍵←n
                         1⍸⍤=⊢∨⍳    Numbers coprime to ⍵
                  ¯1*2×÷×    Divide by ⍵, double, raise -1 to the power of them
{(0,⍵)-⍺×⍵,0}/⍤⌽1,    Evaluate the polynomial with the roots of the above
```

Comment: `((0,⊢)-0,⍨×)` saves a byte

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 81 bytes

```
Round@CoefficientList[Times@@(x-E^(2Pi*I#/k)&/@Select[Range[k=#],#~GCD~k<2&]),x]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>176</s> <s>171</s> <s>139</s> 112 bytes

```r
function(n){for(r in exp(2i*pi*(x=1:n)[(g=function(x,y)ifelse(o<-x%%y,g(y,o),y))(x,n)<2]/n))T=c(0,T)-r*c(T,0)
T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5LasMwEN3nFIISMmPkVsnSWFcwoXgXWnCVUSKwJTOWikzo2V1l064evD9vZjVjiGFyRrT1ZpM30QUPHh82MLBwXlCe4eSq2VWQ9bHxeIGb/nNmuaKzNC4Eoa3zfr/KG6wyYOGxqB7b08ebR@y1ASV7rLky0EuFu/5n68qqOCrxIuYURSfuxLTLT5JD8ld4J/h/CB3iM3cd4vBqeZiKGMhazfQNGWUknvQ8LJEUHPLnQfo0fREvTUNpLHi@u1LRKMTtFw)

Massively simpler version; uses a `for` loop rather than a `Reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (<strike>52</strike> 51 bytes)

```
{M{:K,:!W+K,0-{K\%!},{j($,\:Q,-[{(\1$Qf*.-}*;]}/}j}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=105%0A%7BM%7B%3AK%2C%3A!W%2BK%2C0-%7BK%5C%25!%7D%2C%7Bj(%24%2C%5C%3AQ%2C-%5B%7B(%5C1%24Qf*.-%7D*%3B%5D%7D%2F%7Dj%7D%0A~p). This is an anonymous block (function) which takes an integer on the stack and leaves a big-endian array of coefficients on the stack.

#### Dissection

```
{                    e# Define a block
  M{                 e#   Memoised recursion with no base cases.
    :K,:!W+          e#     Store argument in K and build (x^K - 1)
    K,0-{K\%!},      e#     Find proper divisors of K
    {                e#     Foreach proper divisor D...
      j              e#       Recursive call to get Dth cyclotomic poly
      ($,\:Q,-       e#       The cleverest bit. We know that it is monic, and the
                     e#       poly division is simpler without that leading 1, so
                     e#       pop it off and use it for a stack-based lookup in
                     e#       calculating the number of terms in the quotient.
                     e#       Ungolfed this was (;:Q1$,\,-
                     e#       Store the headless divisor in Q.
      [              e#       Gather terms into an array...
        {            e#         Repeat the calculated number of times...
          (\         e#           Pop leading term, which goes into the quotient.
          1$Qf*.-    e#           Multiply Q by that term and subtract from tail.
        }*;          e#         Discard the array of Q,( zeroes. 
      ]
    }/
  }j
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 91 bytes

Using the formula:

\$ \Phi_n(x)=\dfrac{x^{n}-1}{\prod\limits_{\stackrel{d|n}{{}_{d<n}}}\Phi_{d}(x)} \$.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xCsMwDET3fIUIHSRwqL0a0k8pOHVMTWNZuA7k71Nl6A036O6JK@HIJZxnQiY/L1t9fVAtbCgmkhF/PHlyJtUG0Tvo77aDHiBWzAlKjcjam60mK4N4uSeMRKatfW@MQnQ7L5j/sLNWYcABVNIyd/0AI0wPGA200L@5CF5ziAaFfw)

```
f(n):=block(local(p,d),p:x^n-1,for d:1 thru n-1 do(if mod(n,d)=0 then p:p/f(d)),return(p))$
```

Ungolfed version. Try it online!

```
f(n) := block(
    local(p, d),
    p : x^n - 1,
    for d:1 thru n-1 do (
        if mod(n, d) = 0 then (
            p : p / f(d)
        )
    ),
    return(p)
)$

for n:1 thru 100 do (
    print(n, " -> ", ratsimp(f(n)))
)$
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript(ES6), <s>337</s> <s>333</s> <s>284</s> ... <s>252</s> <s>250</s> <s>245</s> 242 bytes

```
(v,z=[e=[1,u=0]],g=(x,y)=>y?g(y,x%y):x,h=Math,m=(l,x,p=h.cos(l),q=h.sin(l),i=0)=>x.map(()=>[(i&&(n=x[i-1])[0])-(w=x[i])[0]*p+w[1]*q,(i++&&n[1])-w[1]*p-w[0]*q]))=>{for(;++u<v;z=g(v,u)-1?z:[...m(h.PI*2*u/v,z),e]);return z.map(r=>h.round(r[0]))}
```

**Explanation (Selected):**

```
z=[e=[1,u=0]]
```

Initialize z=(1+0i) * x^0

```
g=(x,y)=>y?g(y,x%y):x
```

GCD calculation.

```
h=Math
```

Since I need to use Math functions quite a lot, I used another variable here.

```
m=(l,x,p=h.cos(l),q=h.sin(l),i=-1)=>blah blah blah
```

Polynomial multiplication.

```
for(;++u<v;z=g(v,u)-1?z:[...m(h.PI*2*u/v,z),e]);
```

The formula used is

[image]

```
return z.map(r=>h.round(r[0]))
```

Compress the output back to an integer array.

**Outputs:**

An array of integers, with the element at position i representing the coefficient of x^i.

One of the problem JS have is that since JS does not provide native library for calculations on polynomials and complex numbers, they needed to be implemented in an array-like way.

console.log(phi(105)) gives

```
Array(49)
 0:  1    1:  1    2:  1    3: -0    4: -0    5: -1    6: -1 
 7: -2    8: -1    9: -1   10:  0   11: -0   12:  1   13:  1 
14:  1   15:  1   16:  1   17:  1   18:  0   19: -0   20: -1 
21:  0   22: -1   23: -0   24: -1   25:  0   26: -1   27: -0 
28: -1   29:  0   30:  0   31:  1   32:  1   33:  1   34:  1 
35:  1   36:  1   37: -0   38: -0   39: -1   40: -1   41: -2 
42: -1   43: -1   44: -0   45: -0   46:  1   47:  1   48:  1 
length: 49
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**337>333(-4): Changed the code for checking undefined value**

**333>284(-49): Changed the polynomial multiplication function because it can be simplified**

**284>277(-7): Deleted some redundant code**

**277>265(-12): Use 2 variables instead of a 2-element array to drop some bytes in array usage**

**265>264(-1): Use Array.push() instead of Array.concat() to reduce 4 bytes, but added 3 for the for-loop braces and the z variable**

**264>263(-1): Further golfed on the last amendment**

**263>262(-1): Golfed on the for loop**

**262>260(-2): Golfed out the if clause**

**260>258(-2): Further combined the declarations**

**258>252(-6): Golfed on reuse of array references**

**252>250(-2): Replace some unary operators as binary operators**

**250>245(-5): Move the increment in Array.map() to the last reference of counter to remove bytes**

**245>242(-3): Use spread syntax instead of Array.push()**